# Neo4j Desktop db failed to start after upgrade to 3.5

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I upgraded my db from 3.4.5 to 3.5.1 now it failing to start with a

```
Database failed to start: Database process terminated, see logs.. Check the logs
```

message. The logs show these....:

```
2019-01-08 16:39:28.779+0000 WARN  ha.pull_interval is deprecated.
2019-01-08 16:39:28.815+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.5.1 ========
2019-01-08 16:39:28.824+0000 INFO  Starting...
2019-01-08 16:39:30.351+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2019-01-08 16:39:35.141+0000 INFO  Deprecated index providers in use: lucene-1.0 (6 indexes), lucene+native-2.0 (6 indexes). Use procedure 'db.indexes()' to see what indexes use which index provider.
2019-01-08 16:39:42.347+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at C:\Users\maenn\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-e791f202-143d-4df6-86ef-8981b8539815\installation-3.5.1\metrics
2019-01-08 16:39:43.240+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:11001.
2019-01-08 16:39:45.458+0000 WARN  Server thread metrics not available (missing neo4j.server.threads.jetty.all)
2019-01-08 16:39:45.524+0000 WARN  Server thread metrics not available (missing neo4j.server.threads.jetty.idle)
2019-01-08 16:39:45.970+0000 INFO  Started.
2019-01-08 16:39:46.456+0000 INFO  Mounted REST API at: /db/manage
2019-01-08 16:39:46.493+0000 INFO  Mounted unmanaged extension [org.neo4j.graphql] at [/graphql]
2019-01-08 16:39:46.607+0000 INFO  Server thread metrics have been registered successfully
**2019-01-08 16:39:47.131+0000 ERROR The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.**
**2019-01-08 16:39:47.146+0000 WARN  unavailable The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.**
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
........   
.......
2019-01-08 16:39:47.213+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on 127.0.0.1:11002: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-6ebdb938@c44ac081==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false
**2019-01-08 16:39:47.227+0000 INFO  Stopping...
2019-01-08 16:39:53.156+0000 INFO  Stopped.
2019-01-08 16:39:53.159+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter@6e4dfd4d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.". Starting Neo4j failed: Component** 

........
.........

2019-01-08 16:39:53.161+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

I can see a number of error messages in the logs but I just don't know what they mean. I have indexes in the DB but from my reading that should not prevent a start.   I also removed and re-install version 3.5.0.1 of APOC and Graph Algorithm. The previous answers to similar question don't seem to address my case. Can anyone tell me whats going on here.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ? I am facing the same error.

Comment: No I didn't .....I create a new instance. Let us know if you find a solution. I had to recreate my data...luckily it was just test data.

Comment: Do check your file permissions for `debug.log` and `security.log` files i.e it is the same user that is running neo4j and make sure you build your plugins with the Neo4j latest version.